# r - error using custom LaTeX style file to render PDF using rmarkdown

Tags: r, pdf, latex, r-markdown

Based off of the [answser](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/171711/how-to-include-latex-package-in-r-markdown) by user3143179, I created custom.sty to specify both the fonts and LaTeX packages to use to render a PDF with `rmarkdown`.

Content of **custom.sty** below:

```
%  custom.sty

\usepackage{sectsty} \sectionfont{\centering} \chaptertitlefont{\centering}
\usepackage{xcolor}

% fonts
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{LiberationSerif-Regular.ttf}[
BoldFont = LiberationSerif-Bold.ttf,
ItalicFont = LiberationSerif-Italic.ttf,
BoldItalicFont = LiberationSerif-BoldItalic.ttf ]
\setsansfont{LiberationSans-Regular.ttf}[
BoldFont = LiberationSans-Bold.ttf,
ItalicFont = LiberationSans-Italic.ttf,
BoldItalicFont = LiberationSans-BoldItalic.ttf ]
\setmonofont{LiberationMono-Regular.ttf}[
BoldFont = LiberationMono-Bold.ttf,
ItalicFont = LiberationMono-Italic.ttf,
BoldItalicFont = LiberationMono-BoldItalic.ttf ]

\endinput
```

I used the fontspec manual to create the code above with regards to the specific system fonts.

I ran the following R code:

```
rmarkdown::render("custom.Rmd", pdf_document(highlight = "kate",
fig_caption = FALSE, latex_engine = "lualatex", keep_tex = TRUE, includes 
= includes(in_header = "custom.sty")))
```

This is the output from running the R code:

```
processing file: custom.Rmd
  |.................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: custom.knit.md

/usr/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS custom.utf8.md --to latex
--from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures
--output custom.tex --template /rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default.tex --highlight-style kate
--latex-engine lualatex --include-in-header custom.sty --variable graphics=yes 

/usr/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS custom.utf8.md --to latex
--from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash-implicit_figures
--output custom.pdf --template /rmarkdown/rmd/latex/default.tex --highlight-style kate
--latex-engine lualatex --include-in-header custom.sty --variable graphics=yes
```

Error

```
! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.95 \setmainfont{LiberationSerif-Regular.ttf}[

pandoc: Error producing PDF from TeX source
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
```

I also have the raw .tex file in case you need to review it as well. There is `\begin{document}` in the .tex file.

What other component(s) are needed in the .sty file so that the LaTeX file is properly rendered into PDF format using rmarkdown?

Is there anything else needed in the call to `rmarkdown::render`?

Comment: Which answer are you referring too? There is no (working) link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me when I remove the `\endinput` from `custom.sty`. Problem is that `includes` just like `\include` in TeX inputs the file literally. So it makes more sense to rename `custom.sty` to `header.tex`.

Comment: I added the link to the answer again. Thank you for the suggestion to name the file: header.tex.